# Arima with regressors

Tags: r, time-series, regression

I have some quarterly transactional bookings data which usually I can get to forecast very accurately. However every 4-5 years there is a price change within the company causing the forecasts to be a lot lower or higher than the actual amount. What is the best way to adjust this using `Arima`?

My data begins at 08Q1 and finishes at 15Q1. The first price change occurred in 11Q3 and the second happened 15Q1.

```
data <- ts(c(155782698, 159463653.4, 172741125.6, 200266239.9, 126129831.8, 138648461.5, 135678842.1, 242568446.1, 177019289.3, 200397120.6, 182516217.1, 306143365.6, 215193973.8, 239062450.2, 229124263.2, 370575384.7, 257757410.5, 256125841.6, 231879306.6, 415059425.9, 258567845, 274423841.3, 261799212.9, 429126949.7, 254770376.5, 329422935.1, 264029599.1, 493122080.3, 283776872.9), start=c(8,1), deltat=1/4)

dates <- c("08Q1", "08Q2", "08Q3", "08Q4", "09Q1", "09Q2", "09Q3", "09Q4", "10Q1", "10Q2", "10Q3", "10Q4", "11Q1", "11Q2", "11Q3", "11Q4", "12Q1", "12Q2", "12Q3", "12Q4", "13Q1", "13Q2", "13Q3", "13Q4", "14Q1", "14Q2", "14Q3", "14Q4", "15Q1")
```

I heard that in `Arima` you can apply regressors but I'm not entirely sure exactly what the regressor would be in this case and how to apply it to obtain the forecasts. Has anyone got an idea and can help?

Comment: a think `xreg` argument of `arima` function is what you are looking for

Comment: @AndriyTkach I have heard about the xreg function...however im not completely sure what to put into the vector as the regressors or how to forecast it from there..

Comment: from `help(arima)` I suppose u have to constract a vector/matrix with the same length that your data (in this example 29). If you don't have a price variable so you could use a dummy.

Comment: @AndriyTkach yes but what the content of that vecor would be is what im unsure of...

Comment: wait a minute for my answer

Answer (score 0):

Construct dummy variable for changes in price:

```
prices <- matrix(0, length(dates), 2)

prices[16:29,1] <- 1
prices[29,2] <- 1
```

this is not the best way to construct dummy but the fastest one. I just looked at the position of "11Q3" that is 16 and "15Q1" tah is 29.
So I say dummy 1 for the period 11Q3 - 15Q1 and dummy 2 for 15Q1

And then construct a model:

```
model_reg <- arima(data, xreg = prices)
```

compare with:

```
model <- arima(data)
```

then to predict 3 next quarters you use:

```
predict(model, 3)
predict(model_reg, 3, newxreg = matrix(1, 3, 2))
```

Data:

```
data <- ts(c(155782698, 159463653.4, 172741125.6, 200266239.9, 126129831.8, 138648461.5, 135678842.1, 242568446.1, 177019289.3, 200397120.6, 182516217.1, 306143365.6, 215193973.8, 239062450.2, 229124263.2, 370575384.7, 257757410.5, 256125841.6, 231879306.6, 415059425.9, 258567845, 274423841.3, 261799212.9, 429126949.7, 254770376.5, 329422935.1, 264029599.1, 493122080.3, 283776872.9), start=c(8,1), deltat=1/4)

dates <- c("08Q1", "08Q2", "08Q3", "08Q4", "09Q1", "09Q2", "09Q3", "09Q4", "10Q1", "10Q2", "10Q3", "10Q4", "11Q1", "11Q2", "11Q3", "11Q4", "12Q1", "12Q2", "12Q3", "12Q4", "13Q1", "13Q2", "13Q3", "13Q4", "14Q1", "14Q2", "14Q3", "14Q4", "15Q1")
```

Comment: thankyou for this. may i ask what is the relevance/what is the newxreg variable and why those specific numbers (1,3,2) in that order?

Comment: matrix(1, 3, 2) it is only a simulation of data. About it's meaning I think you should read some articles. start with [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics))